# Getting Latest Library Dependency - Android

Tags: android, gradle, libraries, rx-java, rx-android

I'm new to Gradle and I need to make sure that my Android project has the latest dependencies with regards to **RxAndroid** and **RxJava**. Forgive me for my ignorance but could someone explain how I go about to make sure that the libraries I include in my project are the latest ones? Where does Gradle downloads these libraries from? Is there a central repository? Is GitHub the source? It's not clear from the code shown below:

**build.gradle**

```
    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.14'
    }
```

I would really appreciate if someone could shed some light with regards to this topic.

Comment: you can check their github page https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradle downloads them from Maven or other repos. I don't believe GitHub hosts the libraries themselves, but the link to download the libraries could be found on GitHub.
To ensure they are the latest version, you will have to go the library's web page(Git hub page usually) and check if a latest version has been released.

If I am not wrong, you could add a **+** sign at the end and when you sync Gradle with **work in offline mode turned off**, it should fetch the latest version of the library.
Eg:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0+'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1+'
```

The above line will ensure that `1.0.1` is the min version that you will download and if there are any higher version, it will download that instead.

**WARNING :** this is **not a safe thing** to do, because the latest version of library will be automatically downloaded and the changes in the newer version of the library might have **breaking changes**, and **break your app**. For instance the methods you use from a library might be removed in the new library or even **worse things** could happen and it has to me. I suggest you set some time apart once every few weeks and see if there are new updates and consider if it is safe to update.

Deciding to add a library to your project must be carefully thought through, as you are making the project dependent on it and if that library dies out or is buggy, your project too will be screwed.  Incase you didn't, I suggest you read [this](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/03/23/npm_left_pad_chaos/) on how being careless with adding dependencies literally broke the internet.

Comment: This is a bad practice and the IDEA will warn you not to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the latest:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.0' // Upgraded
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.5' // Upgraded
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

check [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid)

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a plus to the end of each, although it's not recommended as sometimes new libs will break your code.

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0+'
  compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1+'
  compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.14+'
}
```

Comment: This is a bad practice and the IDEA will warn you not to do it.